# Generate mvc View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a View with a model on my website (based on MVC and C#). I want to generate HTML code from those two, without any Controller.

**Why?** Because I'm using SignalR with some Hub. The client pass some arguments and I'm rendering the HTML in server side and return it to client.

Is this possible? If yes, How?

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't want to use a controller...

Comment: Controller isn't needed in this case. In fact, the SignalR hub is acting like "controller".

Comment: isn't needed now but it is bad practice to omit it. What if in the future you wanted to add some logic? How do you unit test without controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)

**RazorEngine**

A templating engine built on Microsoft's Razor parsing engine, RazorEngine allows you to use Razor syntax to build dynamic templates:

To parse your view into plain html you can do something like:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can with the separate [RazorEngine](https://razorengine.codeplex.com/). It gives you the ability to render views without ASP.NET MVC.

But I highly doubt that is what you want in the end. I suggest to keep using the entire ASP.NET MVC eco-system, including Controllers, and fix the problem you have there, rather than moving the problem around.